# Facebbok api: how to get the user name in a specific case (like accusative, genetive, etc.)?

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

In many human languages grammar requires usage of cases like genetive, accusative etc. Facebook itself is capable of declining the (human) names. For example, if the primary language is russian it displays " became friends with " where  is in an instrumental case (form).
Is it possible to get a user name in a specific case using facebook API?

EDIT: at least, it is possible to retrieve the user name in a different language by adding e.g. ?locale=ru_RU to the graph API query.

Comment: Nice question. Though I can bet there is no API methods for that.

Answer (score -1):

Facebook has some details for each user that are saved

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/

Each Facebook user has only 1 "name" field saved and it can be in any language that the user chooses.

When you retrieve this information using Facebook graph-API you will have no indication in what language the information is.

so for your question with using ONLY Facebook API you cant get the user name in a specific case ( genitive, accusative etc) and you cannot add any parameter to the request (?locale=ru_RU)

Comment: Regarding the locale parameter - your answer is incorrect. With ?locale=ru_RU I am able to retrieve the user name in Russian. Without this parameter I get it in English. This feature is not well-documented but it is there.